# How to reset the keystore

Tags: android, release, keystore

So, I try to build my app for release, and I accidentally mistype the password and as I expect, it gives me an error saying that the file was tampered with or that the password was incorrect. I thought I could just retry but it won't let me. It just keeps trying to verify the keystore file with the same messed up password without giving me an option to try again. So, I delete the keystore and now it just keeps saying that it can't find the keystore, yet never gives me the option to specify a new file/location. Is there something I missed?

Comment: I think you need to create a new keystore with the same name of your deleted keystore, store it to the location of your deleted keystore and modify the **Key Alias**, **Key Password**, **Store File** and **Store Password**. and remember if you set a new keystore to your app, the app will also reset if you run that to the different machine.

Comment: "and remember if you set a new keystore to your app, the app will also reset if you run that to the different machine", can you clarify? If I set a new keystore? How would I do that. Also, I try to create a new keystore, but in doing so, android studio tries to build the app, and that in turn causes the incorrect password error